# Why Python 3.8 interpret String like "\x48" as "H". I want to write it as "\x48" in a string

Tags: python, string, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I am using python to code a simple program which take sample c++ ".cpp" file as a string and then find all the strings declared into it. Then i want to replace that string into its equivalent Hexcode like "H"is equal to "\x48".

My code is

```
f = open("sample.cpp", "r")
f1 = f.read()
regex = r"\"(?:(?:(?!(?<!\\)\").)*)\""

ii=0
for str2021 in find:
   print("Output Of Encode=")
   str2021="".join(r'\x{0:x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in find[ii])
   print (str2021)
   ii=ii+1

subst='\x22\x48\x22'
result = re.sub(regex,subst, f1, 0)
if result:
  print("substituted op=")
  print (result)
```

Now when i print result value it shows "H" instead of    "\x22\x48\x22". How can i forcefully do it in python 3.8?

Also if i do it like this
`result = re.sub(regex,str2021, f1, 0)`
it gives an error
`raise s.error('bad escape %s' % this, len(this))`
`re.error: bad escape \x at position 0`

I wanted to iterate it so that at every string found using regex in cpp file then code will automatically convert string into its equivalent unicode hex code like this

**Sample.cpp**
`string a="abc";`
`string b="H";`

It should change this cpp file like this

`string a="\x61\x62\x63";`
`string b="\x48";`

Kindly suggest solution

Comment: The error appears to be with this line `subst='\x22\x48\x22'` which should clearly be a raw string, as you've done in all the other locations you've used `\x` in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use raw strings:

```
subst = r'\x22\x48\x22'
```

Then, also change your re.sub call:

```
re.sub(regex, re.escape(subst), f1, 0)
```

Python doc says, escaping just the backslashes is better, though:

```
re.sub(regex, subst.replace("\\", r"\\"), f1, 0)
```

Comment: I got this error after using your method.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\sre_parse.py", line 1039, in parse_template
    this = chr(ESCAPES[this][1])
KeyError: '\\x

Comment: Actually when this subst string is passed into this function
result = re.sub(regex,subst, f1, 0)
Then is throws error about escape character.

Comment: @AbdulHannan added the re.sub call to my answer.